No native implementation of WebCrypto is available in current context if Next.js app accessed using IP address
My Next.js app runs normal if I tried to access it from 127.0.0.1:8082 or localhost:8082. The problem is when I want to access it using my machine's IP address (e.g. http://10.233.xx.xx:8082/) it throws an error Error: no native implementation of WebCrypto is available in current context.
Based on the error message, this is the source of error:
> const session = require("iron-session/edge");
const cookieSet = {
  cookieName: "cookiename",
  password: "mypass",
  cookieOptions: {
    sameSite: "strict",
    maxAge: 3600,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  },
};


WebCrypto API is available only in secure contexts like HTTPS.

@Topaco yep, after creating my own ssl on my local it works now! However, I got the same error while building my next project from my remote server using SSH. Any idea why this happens?

My guess is that session imported from "iron-session/edge" is designed to work only in Nextjs's edge runtime, where WebCrypto API is not included (Ref: Edge and Nodejs runtimes).
Thus, const session = require("iron-session") probably would work, by using nodejs version from iron-session library (if your code is not in Middleware).
